# QChar to uint32_t conversion / casting in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, casting, qstring, qchar

I have a `QString` of 1500 `QChar` which I want to convert to an array of `uint32_t`. I am reading each element in for loop and trying to save each `QChar` of `QString` to `uint32_t` array. I can convert it to its equivalent representation (e.g. 1 -> 49) through `data[i].unicode()` but I want the same string in an `uint32_t` array form for further processing.

```
QString data = {1,'A','C',9,8,.....};
uint32_t Test[data.length()] = {0};
for (uint32_t i =0; i<data.length(); i++) {
    Test[i] = data[i]; // here i need QChar to uint32_t conversion
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Isn't `uint16_t` much suitable data type for such conversion? Note, that `QChar` represents 16 bits.

Comment: What do you want saved in the uint32? As UTF8, UTF16 or UTF32? Also, quoting the QT website: "The QChar class provides a 16-bit Unicode character."

Comment: I want to save it as uint32_t. After conversion I will pass this to another function that accepts an array of uint32_t type only. A Qstring of 8 QChars can be converted to uint32_t type using `data.toUInt(nullptr,16)` but as I have a very long string I need to do each individual item seprately.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what you mean by the word *convert*. That word is almost meaningless by itself. `string.toUInt(...)` is a means to convert a textual representation of a number into an integer, e.g. `Q_ASSERT(QStringLiteral("789ABC").toUint({},16) == 0x789ABC)`. At the very minimum, please provide some conversion examples stated as assertions on some `convert` function that you seek that you intend to hold. That's a good way of specifying what you expect said `convert` function to do.

Comment: I want to store items of `QString data` in `uint32_t Test[]` array. E.g. If I have `QString data = {1,'A','C',9,8,.....}` as input than at output I want to have `uint32_t Test = {1,'A','C',9,8,.....}`.

Comment: Does your code compile? What is the output you obtain with your current code?

Comment: @aly Please edit the question to make it complete and then delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that each `QChar` holds only 16 bits and consist of two parts: cell and row, you can even pack two `QChar`s into a single `uint32_t` number. I would do it in the following way:

```
QString data("ABCDE");
std::vector<uint32_t> test((data.count() + 1) / 2, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i)
{
    const QChar &c = data[i];
    uchar cell = c.cell();
    uchar row = c.row();

    uint32_t &ui32 = test[i / 2];
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        ui32 = cell;
    }
    else
    {
        ui32 <<= 8;
        ui32 |= cell;
    }
    ui32 <<= 8;
    ui32 |= row;
}
```

However if you still need to have a single integer number per `QChar` you can write similar loop without compression like:

```
QString data("ABCDE");    
std::vector<uint32_t> test(data.count(), 0);

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i)
{
    const QChar &c = data[i];
    uchar cell = c.cell();
    uchar row = c.row();

    uint32_t &ui32 = test[i];
    ui32 = cell;
    ui32 <<= 8;
    ui32 |= row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store items of `QString` data in `uint32_t Test[]` array. E.g. If I have `QString data = {1,'A','C',9,8,.....}` as input than at output I want to have `uint32_t Test = {1,'A','C',9,8,.....}`

It's not complicated at all. Each `QChar` is a thin wrapper around `uint16_t`. All you need to do is to convert those to `uint32_t` and you're done.

```
QVector<uint32_t> convert(const QString & str) {
  QVector<uint32_t> output;
  output.reserve(str.size());
  for (auto c : str)
    output.append(c.unicode());
  return output;
}

void user(const uint32_t *, size_t size);

void test(const QString & str) {
  auto const data = convert(str);
  user(data.data(), size_t(data.size());
}
```

Of course it might be that you have wrong assumptions about the **meaning** of `uint32_t`. The code above assumes that the `user` expects UTF16 code units. It's more likely, though, that `user` expects UTF32 code units, i.e. each `uint32_t` represents exactly one Unicode code point.

In the latter case, you have to convert conjugate pairs of UTF16 code units to single UTF32 code units:

```
QVector<uint32_t> convert(const QString & str) {
  return str.toUcs4();
}
```

Note that code point and code unit have specific meanings and are *not* synonymous.